# iPhone - Downloading A File - Access Error

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

While I am using Xamarin and not XCode I would think any Xcode developer would be able to answer this question as well.
I am trying to download a file, but I am getting an exception thrown, supposedly I don't have authorization.

Here is my code:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // iOS 7 and earlier
var fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine (documentsFolder, "example.xml");

if(!File.Exists(documentsFolder)){
        //For some reason the directory doesn't exist and doesn't appear that it is being created
        Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsFolder);

}

webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/example/example.xml", fileNameAndPath);
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
System.Net.WebException: An error occurred performing a WebClient request. ---> System.Exception: Access to the path '/private/var/mobile/Applications/AF41E8B3-BB83-45F4-89AC-5BC4FE514E95/Documents/example.xml' is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x0034b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:122
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileCore (System.Uri address, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00002] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.16/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:318
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.Uri address, System.String fileName) [0x00035] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.16/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:303
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.Uri address, System.String fileName) [0x00047] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.16/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:307
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.String address, System.String fileName) [0x00011] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.16/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:290
  at com.turboverse.scripturememory.UpdateVersesViewController.DownloadVersesButton_TouchUpInside (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton sender) [0x00035] in /Users/apple/Projects/com.turboverse.scripturememory/com.example.example/UpdateVersesViewController.cs:31
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:45
  at com.turboverse.scripturememory.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/apple/Projects/com.example.example/com.example.example/Main.cs:17
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If path describes a directory, this method returns false.

from MSDN [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> WebException - The file does not exist.

So you need to

1. Don't check for the folder's existence.  It's safe to assume it exists in iOS
2. create the file before you call DownloadFile